# Variable extracted from JSON object in array logs correctly to console within the loop, but returns undefined when used for summation in same loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, javascript-objects

I want to loop through some objects in an array and add their values together. I can log the values of each key individually, like so:

```
console.log(workouts[0].exercises[0].break);
```

but when I insert them into the loop, the console returns the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'duration' of undefined

If I put the line targeting "break" first, it says it can't read property 'break' of undefined, which should mean "exercises" is not defined correctly, but as I said before I can get it to log its values no problem.

How can I be able to log the correct value if it is not definable?
Here is my code:

```
  var workouts = {
  "workouts":
  [
    {
      "title": "Full Body",
      "exercises":
      [
        {
          "name": "Push Ups",
          "duration": 30,
          "break": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Squats",
          "duration": 30,
          "break": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Running in Place",
          "duration": 30,
          "break": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  };

  for (var  i = 0; i < workouts.length; i++)
  {
    for (var  k = 0; k != workouts.length; k++)
    var durations = workouts[i].exercises[k].duration;
    var breaks = workouts[i].exercises[k].break;
    var totalTime = durations + durations;
    console.log(totalTime);
  }
```

Comment: you code have syntax error just before the end of workout object

Comment: You're using the index of `workouts` (`i`) also for `exercises`

Comment: Let me know if you have resolved it already @Brian

Answer (score 1):

Try `workouts["workouts"][i].exercises[k].break`. And don't use `i` of workout object also to loop through exercises. Get the length with exercises.length and create a new loop with that.

Comment: Where does `k` coming from ?

Comment: `for(let k = 0; k != exercises.length; k++) { console.log (workouts["workouts"][i].exercises[k].break) }` @Andreas

Comment: Thank you, this helped me understand better how to use loops. However the problem persists and I am not sure why you would add ["workouts"] after workouts in the log. I tried this also and it didn't work, same error message.

Comment: It's just a simple spelling mistake. Re check the spelling of exercises in the part which is broken.

Answer (score 1):

```
var workouts = {
  "workouts":
  [
    {
      "title": "Full Body",
      "exercises":
      [
        {
          "name": "Push Ups",
          "duration": 30,
          "break": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Squats",
          "duration": 30,
          "break": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Running in Place",
          "duration": 30,
          "break": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  };
console.log(workouts.workouts[0].exercises.length)
  for (var  i = 0; i < workouts.workouts[0].exercises.length; i++)
  {
    console.log(workouts.workouts[0].exercises[i].break); 
    var durations = workouts.workouts[0].exercises[i].duration; 
    var breaks = workouts.workouts[0].exercises[i].break;
    var totalTime = durations + breaks;
    console.log(totalTime);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the array I provided is just a shortened version of the one I have (I wanted to keep this question to a minimum) so I still need to index the workouts, as there are more of them. I updated my question, still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your syntax.

`var breaks = workouts[i].excercises[i].break;`

should be `var breaks = workouts[i].exercises[i].break;`

Moreover, use nested loops for iterating over exercises array like my fellows suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing this is needed with more data from the JSON:

> the workouts["workouts"] part is needed for objects, they need the key and not only the array index number [n]. Can also be written as workouts.workouts[n].exercises[n].

```
var workouts = {
  "workouts": [{
    "title": "Full Body",
    "exercises": [{
      "name": "Push Ups",
      "duration": 30,
      "break": 10
    }, {
      "name": "Squats",
      "duration": 30,
      "break": 10
    }, {
      "name": "Running in Place",
      "duration": 30,
      "break": 10
    }]
  }, {
    "title": "Lower Body",
    "exercises": [{
      "name": "Squats",
      "duration": 30,
      "break": 10
    }, {
      "name": "Running in Place",
      "duration": 30,
      "break": 10
    }]
  }]
};

var totalTime = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < workouts["workouts"].length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < workouts["workouts"][i].exercises.length; j++) {
    var durations = workouts["workouts"][i].exercises[j].duration;
    var breaks = workouts["workouts"][i].exercises[j].break;
    totalTime = totalTime + durations + breaks;
    console.log(workouts.workouts[i].title + " (" + workouts.workouts[i].exercises[j].name + "): " + (durations+breaks) + " \n ");
  }
}
console.log("total: " +totalTime);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but console still returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" at the line where you first state your "for" loop (just after "var totalTime = 0"). i am starting to suspect there is something wrong with the object I am getting back from the server.

Comment: try adding debug code like these:
`console.log(workouts); // [object Object]`
`console.log(workouts.length); // undefined`
`console.log(workouts.workouts); // [object Object],[object Object],...`
`console.log(workouts.workouts.length); // number of workouts`